# $IM=mM$. can we say that $I$ is a reduction ideal of $m$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

**Question**. Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring and $M$ be a finite *faithful* $R$-module. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $IM=mM$. Can we say that $I$ is a *reduction ideal* of $m$? Recall that $I$ is a reduction ideal of $m$ if $Im^n=m^{n+1}$ for some (or equivalently all) sufficiently large $n$.

If not what conditions can we add (on $I$ or $R$ or...) to be able to say $I$ is a *reduction ideal* of $m$?

Thank you.

Comment: also asked in math.stackexchange.com (24 days ago, with no answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is always yes.  It's a basic tool in studying the integral closures of ideals.

Let $x \in m$.  Let $\phi: M \rightarrow M$ be the endomorphism of $M$ given by multiplication by $x$.  Then since $\phi(M) \subseteq IM$, the Cayley-Hamilton theorem shows that there exist $a_j \in I^j$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $$
\phi^n + \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \phi^{n-j}=0
$$
as an element of the endomorphism ring of $M$.  But since $M$ is faithful, it follows that $x^n + \sum_{j=1}^n a_j x^{n-j}=0 \in R$.  Thus, $x$ is in the integral closure of the ideal $I$.

Since this holds for an arbitrary element of $m$, it follows that $I$ is a reduction of $m$.

Comment: Oh.  Well, if $\phi$ is the endomorphism of multiplication by $x$ on $M$, then $\psi := \phi^n + \sum a_j \phi^{n-j}$ is the endomorphism given by multiplication by $y := x^n +\sum a_j x^{n-j}$. on $M$.  And so, to say that $\psi$ is the zero map on $M$ (which it is, by the C-H theorem) is the same as saying that $y$ annihilates $M$.  But ``$M$ is faithful'' means that only $0$ annihilates $M$.  Hence $y=0$.